# how to display selected row in textbox MVP c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, design-patterns, datagridview

**I have MVP project iam trying to display the selected row to 3 textboxs and 1 checkbox :
i know i can do it from the CellClick event like so :**

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int index = e.RowIndex;// get the Row Index
    DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridView1.Rows[index];
    textBox1.Text = selectedRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    textBox2.Text = selectedRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    textBox3.Text = selectedRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    textBox4.Text = selectedRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    checkBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(selectedRow.Cells[4].Value);
}
```

**But i want to call it from other class called Presenter but iam getting errors :**

**1.The name 'e' does not exist in the current context .**
**2. 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Rows' and no accessible extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) .**
**3.Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'.**

Thanks...

Comment: What is the class "Presenter"? Call the method `dataGridView1_CellClick`? How did you call it? Could you provide more specific info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salem, for what I can see in your code, and based on your explanation you have an event click and you want to trigger that one from the presenter itself, so I think this is not a correct approach, I will go by extracting the method from the click and calling from the presenter the new method, I guess you will need a way to get the Index from the presenter and pass it as an argument.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int index = e.RowIndex;// get the Row Index
    CheckRowBoxByID(index);
}

void FillDataWithRowByID(int index){
    DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridView1.Rows[index];
    textBox1.Text = selectedRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    textBox2.Text = selectedRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    textBox3.Text = selectedRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    textBox4.Text = selectedRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    checkBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(selectedRow.Cells[4].Value);
}
```

This is a high overview, it could be incorrect but I'll go with having a segregation of responsibilities. and from the presenter call below method.

```
FillDataWithRowByID(withTheIntID);
```

Basically the errors you get it are because:

1. You're trying to create an event that doesn't exist in the
   presenter.
2. Passing an Objet as a Row.
3. Passing a String as Integer

Hopes it makes sense, Cheers.